# Command failed to execute : ant jar on Zend Studio

Tags: android, zend-framework, cordova, ant, zend-studio

```
`cordova library for "android" already exists. No need to download. Continuing.
Checking if platform "android" passes minimum requirements...
Checking Android requirements...
Running "android list target" (output to follow)
Available Android targets:
----------
id: 1 or "android-16"
     Name: Android 4.1.2
     Type: Platform
     API level: 16
     Revision: 4
     Skins: HVGA, QVGA, WQVGA400, WQVGA432, WSVGA, WVGA800 (default), WVGA854, WXGA720, WXGA800, WXGA800-7in
 Tag/ABIs : default/armeabi-v7a
----------
id: 2 or "android-17"
     Name: Android 4.2.2
     Type: Platform
     API level: 17
     Revision: 2
     Skins: HVGA, QVGA, WQVGA400, WQVGA432, WSVGA, WVGA800 (default), WVGA854, WXGA720, WXGA800, WXGA800-7in
 Tag/ABIs : default/armeabi-v7a
----------
id: 3 or "android-18"
     Name: Android 4.3
     Type: Platform
     API level: 18
     Revision: 2
     Skins: HVGA, QVGA, WQVGA400, WQVGA432, WSVGA, WVGA800 (default), WVGA854, WXGA720, WXGA800, WXGA800-7in
 Tag/ABIs : default/armeabi-v7a
----------
id: 4 or "android-19"
     Name: Android 4.4.2
     Type: Platform
     API level: 19
     Revision: 3
     Skins: HVGA, QVGA, WQVGA400, WQVGA432, WSVGA, WVGA800 (default), WVGA854, WXGA720, WXGA800, WXGA800-7in
 Tag/ABIs : default/armeabi-v7a, default/x86
----------
id: 5 or "android-20"
     Name: Android 4.4W
     Type: Platform
     API level: 20
     Revision: 1
     Skins: HVGA, QVGA, WQVGA400, WQVGA432, WSVGA, WVGA800 (default), WVGA854, WXGA720, WXGA800, WXGA800-7in, AndroidWearRound, AndroidWearSquare, AndroidWearRound, AndroidWearSquare
 Tag/ABIs : android-wear/armeabi-v7a, android-wear/x86
----------
id: 6 or "Google Inc.:Google APIs:16"
     Name: Google APIs
     Type: Add-On
     Vendor: Google Inc.
     Revision: 3
     Description: Android + Google APIs
     Based on Android 4.1.2 (API level 16)
     Libraries:
      * com.android.future.usb.accessory (usb.jar)
          API for USB Accessories
      * com.google.android.media.effects (effects.jar)
          Collection of video effects
      * com.google.android.maps (maps.jar)
          API for Google Maps
     Skins: WQVGA432, HVGA, WQVGA400, WVGA854, WVGA800 (default), WXGA720, WXGA800-7in, WXGA800, QVGA, WSVGA
 Tag/ABIs : default/armeabi-v7a
----------
id: 7 or "Google Inc.:Google APIs:17"
     Name: Google APIs
     Type: Add-On
     Vendor: Google Inc.
     Revision: 3
     Description: Android + Google APIs
     Based on Android 4.2.2 (API level 17)
     Libraries:
      * com.android.future.usb.accessory (usb.jar)
          API for USB Accessories
      * com.google.android.media.effects (effects.jar)
          Collection of video effects
      * com.google.android.maps (maps.jar)
          API for Google Maps
     Skins: WSVGA, HVGA, WXGA800-7in, WXGA720, WQVGA400, WXGA800, WQVGA432, WVGA800 (default), WVGA854, QVGA
 Tag/ABIs : default/armeabi-v7a
----------
id: 8 or "Google Inc.:Google APIs:18"
     Name: Google APIs
     Type: Add-On
     Vendor: Google Inc.
     Revision: 3
     Description: Android + Google APIs
     Based on Android 4.3 (API level 18)
     Libraries:
      * com.android.future.usb.accessory (usb.jar)
          API for USB Accessories
      * com.google.android.media.effects (effects.jar)
          Collection of video effects
      * com.google.android.maps (maps.jar)
          API for Google Maps
     Skins: WXGA800-7in, QVGA, WSVGA, WXGA720, HVGA, WXGA800, WQVGA432, WQVGA400, WVGA800 (default), WVGA854
 Tag/ABIs : default/armeabi-v7a
----------
id: 9 or "Google Inc.:Google APIs:19"
     Name: Google APIs
     Type: Add-On
     Vendor: Google Inc.
     Revision: 6
     Description: Android + Google APIs
     Based on Android 4.4.2 (API level 19)
     Libraries:
      * com.android.future.usb.accessory (usb.jar)
          API for USB Accessories
      * com.google.android.media.effects (effects.jar)
          Collection of video effects
      * com.google.android.maps (maps.jar)
          API for Google Maps
     Skins: WSVGA, WQVGA400, HVGA, WVGA854, WQVGA432, WVGA800 (default), WXGA800, WXGA720, WXGA800-7in, QVGA
 Tag/ABIs : default/armeabi-v7a
----------
id: 10 or "Google Inc.:Google APIs (x86 System Image):19"
     Name: Google APIs (x86 System Image)
     Type: Add-On
     Vendor: Google Inc.
     Revision: 6
     Description: Android x86 + Google APIs
     Based on Android 4.4.2 (API level 19)
     Libraries:
      * com.android.future.usb.accessory (usb.jar)
          API for USB Accessories
      * com.google.android.media.effects (effects.jar)
          Collection of video effects
      * com.google.android.maps (maps.jar)
          API for Google Maps
     Skins: WSVGA, WQVGA400, HVGA, WVGA854, WQVGA432, WVGA800 (default), WXGA800, WXGA720, WXGA800-7in, QVGA
 Tag/ABIs : default/x86

Running "android update project -p "C:\Users\Encoder\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.1.0\framework" -t android-17" (output to follow)...
Updated project.properties
Updated local.properties
build.xml: Found version-tag: custom. File will not be updated.
Updated file C:\Users\Encoder\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.1.0\framework\proguard-project.txt
It seems that there are sub-projects. If you want to update them
please use the --subprojects parameter.

Running bin/create for platform "android" with command: ""C:\Users\Encoder\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.1.0\bin\create"  "C:\Users\Encoder\Zend\workspaces\DefaultWorkspace10\MobApp\platforms\android" "org.codova" "MobApp"" (output to follow)
Creating Cordova project for the Android platform:
Command failed to execute : ant jar

Error: An error occured during creation of android sub-project. Creating Cordova project for the Android platform:
Command failed to execute : ant jar

    at C:\Users\Encoder\.zend\cordova\nodejs\node_modules\cordova\src\platform.js:324:35
    at C:\Users\Encoder\.zend\cordova\nodejs\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\shelljs\shell.js:1707:7
    at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:641:7)
    at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:735:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:802:5)`
```

I want to create cloud connected mobile project with Zend studio 10.6.I create , deploy , but when i want to convert to android application this error appears. Although i install ant .
Please , help me :( I don't understand anything. i did all what i could , but i couldn't get any result :(

Comment: Please post your entire stacktrace

Comment: Engineer Dollery , I edited my post.